# store a node into (object) into an array

Tags: php, drupal

I've this piece of code, it retrieves a node from my node type 'Student'.
I try different things to, save all values in `'$node'` into an array. But $node is a object. 
My question is how doe I store 'all' values in `$node` into a array. In Java an C# it's simpler to do that.

```
$results = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type =
 'student'"));

while($nid = db_result($results)) {

  $node = node_load($nid);

  // Do something with $node

}
```

in java or c# you can say in a for/foreach/while 'loop'

```
String item[] = null;
for(int i = 0; i<=myNode; i++) {
   item.add(myNode[i]); // the item and value UgentID, name student, location student are been stored in item array.
}
```

I don't know if PHP has that too. "yourObject.Add(otherObject)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following let's your object behave (access-wise) as an array:

```
$result = new ArrayObject( $node );
```

If you truly want an array, simply cast it afterwards:

```
$result = (array) $result;
```

Heck, come to think of it, you could even simply do:

```
$result = (array) $node;
```

:-)

Both methods of casting to array will actually expose protected/private properties as well, I just found out. :-S Horrible.

**edit:**

```
// initiate array
$nodes = array();
while($nid = db_result($results)) {

  // either do one of the following, to push
  $nodes[] = node_load($nid);

  // or:
  array_push( $nodes, node_load($nid) );

  // Do something with $node

}
```

Comment: But, i don't understand. If a do var_dump($node) in the 'while loop' I can see "all" values. When I doe this outside the wile loop, I just see the latest value. It's the same if I copy it to an array. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You want to append the new values to an array? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Or actually, on further inspection, I don't know what you mean exactly. :-/ Can you edit your question and show an example of how you would do it in Java? Then I'll understand your problem better I think.